# How can I post a photo to instagram that was on my computer and not taken from my iPhone?

Tags: itunes, iphone, macos, instagram

I want to use a photo from my computer and put it on my instagram account. The problem is that when I go to choose the picture, its not shown in the list of images in the /DCIM/100APPLE folder. I believe the issue is that it doesn't have all of the meta data about how the picture was taken so the software doesn't show it.

Someone has said that you need iTunes to do anything on your phone but I'm running linux and iTunes isn't available for my operating system.

Is this the only option? What can I do?

Comment: Send it to yourself by mail and read the mail on your iPhone ;)

Comment: Is the `/DCIM/100APPLE` folder on your computer, or is that on your mounted iPhone? Is the problem that the picture doesn't appear there after copying it from elsewhere on your computer, or is the photo *originating* in that folder?

Comment: @DanJ thats on my mounted iPhone and I moved files there and they do not show up in my list of images when i pick one from instagram app.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler if that works, I'll let you know and you should post it as an answer and I'll accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Send the photo to yourself
2. Save it to camera roll from the mail you just sent to yourself.
3. Post it on instagram

That's it ;)

Comment: thanks this worked! Was having trouble with my gmal app but I connected my gmail to the default mail app with my iphone and saved the picture to the camera roll.